# CSS alignment issues with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, sass

I need a little help in CSS absolute positioning. I am facing some alignment issues. There is an image of a girl who is wearing spectacles and her eyes are rotating basically its a gif image. I used absolute positioning to align the specs and the eyes but it seems the specs and her eyes are not aligning properly. I am attaching a codepen demo for you to understand the problem clearly. Please check the codepen and help me to figure out the issue. Any help will be much appreciable.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap");
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html body {
  background-color: #121212;
}

html body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 12px;
}

html body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

html body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

html body::-moz-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 12px;
}

html body::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
}

html body::-moz-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

html body .rotating-eye {
  position: relative;
}

html body .rotating-eye .eye-rotate-animation {
  height: 100vh !important;
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .eye-rotate-animation {
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: auto !important;
  }
}

html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper img {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin: 2% auto;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper .animate-down {
  font: 25px "Staatliches", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40 / 71) {
  html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper .animate-down {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    margin-top: -26px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper .animate-down {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
}

html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70vh;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .blue-hair {
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: -200px; */
  width: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  top: 6rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .blue-hair {
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .face {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2rem;
  right: 0;
  margin: 2% auto;
  width: 8%;
}

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40 / 71) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .face {
    width: 40% !important;
    margin: 15% auto !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .face {
    margin: 18% auto;
    width: 32%;
  }
}

html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .eye-balls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 40%;
  width: 6%;
}

@media screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .eye-balls {
    margin-top: -42% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .eye-balls {
    margin: -26% 0 0 -18%;
    width: 25%;
  }
}

html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .specs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  width: 8%;
  top: 36%;
}

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40 / 71) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .specs {
    width: 40% !important;
    margin: -30% 0 0 -26% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .specs {
    margin-top: -50% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .specs {
    width: 35%;
    margin: -32% 0 0 -22%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--- rotating eye section -->
<section class="rotating-eye">
  <div class="eye-rotate-animation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="speech-wrapper">
        <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/speech-bubble.png" class="bubble-speech">
        <p class="animate-down">
          Maybe it's time to tip the scales.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wrap-img">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/Layer-1.png" loading="lazy" class="blue-hair">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/no-eye.png" loading="lazy" class="face">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/eye-balls.gif" loading="lazy" class="eye-balls">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/specs.png" loading="lazy" class="specs">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--- rotating eye section ends -->
```

[codepen demo link](https://codepen.io/c-baruah/pen/oNLEMWE?editors=0110)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap");
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html body {
  background-color: #121212;
}
html body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 12px;
}
html body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
html body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
html body::-moz-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 12px;
}
html body::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
}
html body::-moz-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
html body .rotating-eye {
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .eye-rotate-animation {
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: auto !important;
  }
}
html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper img {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin: 2% auto;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper .animate-down {
  font: 25px "Staatliches", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40 / 71) {
  html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper .animate-down {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    margin-top: -26px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .speech-wrapper .animate-down {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    right: 15px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
}
html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding-top: 0;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .blue-hair {
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: -200px; */
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  top: 6rem;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .blue-hair {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .face {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  right: 0;
  margin: 120px auto 30px;
  width: 45%;
}
html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .eye-balls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 94px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 175px;
  width: 36%;
}
html body .rotating-eye .wrap-img .specs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 149px;
}
```

```html
<!--- rotating eye section -->
<section class="rotating-eye">
  <div class="eye-rotate-animation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="speech-wrapper">
        <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/speech-bubble.png" class="bubble-speech">
        <p class="animate-down">
          Maybe it's time to tip the scales.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wrap-img">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/Layer-1.png" loading="lazy" class="blue-hair">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/no-eye.png" loading="lazy" class="face">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/eye-balls.gif" loading="lazy" class="eye-balls">
          <img src="https://tech4good.pacewisdom.in/assets/images/fourth-section/specs.png" loading="lazy" class="specs">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--- rotating eye section ends -->
```

You can also check on [codepen](https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/xxOYJaY)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the same top and left values to the eye-balls and to the specs to make sure they render from the same point.

you can make minor adjustments accordingly to the eye-balls.

Comment: Hi, I tried adjusting the values but the thing is that on my screen the alignments are perfect however on other screens with the same screen resolution the elements are getting misaligned. Please check the codepen demo you will be able to understand clearly. https://codepen.io/c-baruah/pen/oNLEMWE?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be just a matter of tinkering with the values. I adjusted the values of your code a bit.

```
.eye-balls {
      position: absolute;
      left: 46%;
      top: 70%;
      width: 6%;
      // margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
      @media #{$iphonex} {
        margin-top: -42% !important;
      }
      @media #{$mq7b} {
        margin: -26% 0 0 -18%;
        width: 25%;
      }
    }
    .specs {
      position: absolute;
      left: 45%;
      width: 8%;
      bottom: 10%;
```

Is this the solution that you are going for?

Comment: Hi bro the absolute values are not consistent across different screens.